# Accessing list in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a tictactoe program and I've ran into the problem of accessing a certain list in a list consisting of lists.

```
sign = '-'
size = 5
def createGamePlan(size, sign):
  gamePlan = []
  i = 0
  row = [sign]*size
  while i < size:
    gamePlan.append(row)
    i += 1
  return gamePlan

print (createGamePlan(size, sign))
```

Above is my code, which returns:

```
 [['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```

For my program to work I need to be able to access one of these lists to swap out a `-` with whichever sign needs to replace it.

Also, what would be the best way to go about replacing an element in a list?

Comment: Which one would you like to swap?

Comment: Either and any one really, I'm guessing something like 

`gamePlan[1][2] = "X"`

could work for instance,

Comment: Exactly, it will depend on the use-case.

Comment: I'm having a hard time putting my thoughts into words but would it be possible to only replace one '-' in one of the lists somehow?

Comment: You just said it, `gamePlan[1][2] = "X"` would work.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm getting

 `[['-', '-', 'X', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', 'X', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', 'X', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', 'X', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', 'X', '-', '-']]`

Returned which isn't what I was after. (Just to clarify, I want only one '-' in one of the lists within the list to be replaced)

Comment: Slicing(!) that's what I was looking for, I guess the thought just didn't cross my mind. Thank you for you help, definitely the right answer.